# Filtering Array with NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to filter an `array` with `NSPredicate`, but it always returns an `empty array`.

Code:

```
_contentFilteredArray = [_contentArray mutableCopy];
[_contentFilteredArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"special == 1"]]; // Always return an empty array.
```

Original _contentArray:

```
(
    {
    id = 1;
    special = 0;
},
    {
    id = 2;
    special = 1;
},
    {
    id = 3;
    special = 1;
},
    {
    id = 4;
    special = 0;
    }
)
```

What I Expect to _contentFilteredArray:

```
(
    {
    id = 2;
    special = 1;
},
    {
    id = 3;
    special = 1;
},
)
```

Comment: That should work if the values are NSNumbers. Try this log, and see what it gives you: NSLog (@"%@",[_contentArray[1][@"special"] class]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, more following the traditional `withFormat` methods.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"special == %@", @1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the items in the array are key-value coding compliant for the key `special`.  Does

```
   [item valueforKey: @"special"]
```

return the expected numeric value?